# spring web flow + ajax data transfer

Tags: ajax, json, spring

I have been using spring mvc for a while, but now i have started with Spring web flow. and trying to create apps easily using swf.

my doubt is:

I have a JSP , where i have few textboxes to be populated by the user. I want to transfer this user data to the spring controller via flow.xml.

so how do i do that..??

here is my jsp(ajax code)

```
    var postData = {};
    postData["school_name"] = $("#school_name").val();
    postData["borrower_address_zip_code"] = $("#borrower_address_zip_code").val();
    postData["student_enrollment"] = $("#student_enrollment").val();
      $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify(postData),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        url : '${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=handel1&ajaxSource=true',
        cache : false,
        success : function(data) {
        alert('done');
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('textStatus'+textStatus + 'errorThrown'+errorThrown);
         }
    });
```

and here is my flow.xml.

```
    <transition on="handel1">
      <!-- requestParameters -->
          <evaluate expression="studentLoan.createProperty(*********)"
              result="flowScope.content123" />
      </transition>
```

What should i have in place of *********** so that i can hold the data, and invoke the createProperty method, present in controller.

I have got a turn around for this , by using "requestParameters" in place of **********. and passing the javascript array in the query string .
So is this fine???? 
OR
If there is some other better way of doing the same. then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any response to this problem, so i preferred using spring mvc for this particular issue.

I realized spring webflow sits over spring mvc , so its ok to use mvc + webflow, based upon your application requirement.